# Ejercicio sencillo para aprender AJAX

Tags: ajax

Como quiero aprender AJAX, estoy buscando un ejercicio muy simple tipo "hola mundo" pero sobre AJAX. Que tenga pocas líneas de código, a ser posible lo más simple posible. He googleado un poco, y no encuentro nada super fácil. También he visto [este tutorial en udemy](https://www.udemy.com/curso-de-jquery/), pero yo no sé Jquery aún. También he visto otros recursos pero me lo relacionan con PHP y tampoco sé PHP. Me gustaría un ejercicio que solo tuviera javascript, html y css y de momento nada más.

Comment: Ya revisaste [esta documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)? A la vista se siente bastante ligera e intuitiva, por otro lado te recomiendo que aprendas JQuery ya que es mas practico así.

Comment: aprende a usar javascript puro primero, aprende sobre el `xmlHttpRequest` y sobre la API nueva que es `fetch` es una muy mala idea @DєηyηCrawford recomendarle `JQuery` cuando a todas luces el OP esta iniciando

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo @shadow, sin argumento para debatir, solo trataba de complementarle con lo que el menciono! Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Por favor lea los comentarios en el codigo.

```html
function cargar() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // cuando el estado cambie. . . 
  /*
  el valor para readyState puede ser:
  0: UNSENT o sea: sin enviar
  1: OPENED o sea: ha abierto el documento
  2: HEADERS_RECEIVED: enviado y headers recibidos
  3: LOADING: se esta descargando
  4: DONE: ya hay respuesta.


  El estatus puede ser: 
  404: no encontrado
  403: forbidden: prohibido
  . . . .
  200 OK
  */

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // si hay una respuesta y status 200 OK
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // utiliza el resultado 
      callback(responseText);
      // tambien puedes utilizar responseXML en lugar de responseText si la respuesta que esperas es un XML
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();


  function callback(respuesta){
  // haz algo con esta respuesta:
  console.log(respuesta)
  }
  }
}
```